# QGIS: multipolygon vector shapefile -> problem to correct latitude

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geometry, coordinates, multi-polygon

I am currently working with QGIS for my master thesis (without much previous experience).

I was provided with a shapefile containing MPAs (marine protected areas: see picture below).
The latitude is slightly off the correct coordinates (about 2 degress southern than it should, in the northern limit off all polygons), which impacts my project since I need to calculate different areas inside the polygons (wrong latitude = wrong areas).

I checked and both my basemap (first layer added) and the shapefile have the same CRS: EPSG:3031 - WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic.

How can I modify the polygons in my shapefile? I need to expand the latitude, without changing anything else (longitudinal shape, southern limit-antarctic continent). So basically 'add' more to the northern limit of the polygons.

[image]

I have seen in other posts that the processing tool 'Affine transform' might help, but in my case the only options in my QGIS version 3.28.7 are the following:

[image]

I have tried 'playing around' with the vector geometry, but the tool only allows to expand the geometry (it increases the overall shape in size proportionately, basically scaling up all aspects of the visual output).

Could someone provide me with some advice?

Comment: Do you have the exact coordinates of the zone you need to expend ? if so you could edit vertex coordinate to change the latitude (see https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#editing and more specificaly https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-vertex-editor-panel) Be carrefull as you need to input the coordinate in the shapefile CRS, not in lat/lon

Comment: Also I'm not familiar with EPSG:3031 - WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic but if you need accurate area check that this CRS is suitable for that...

Comment: I have the exact coordinates, and I've checked that this CRS is suitable for what I need to do. The vertex edit tool works! Thank you so much!